# How to resolve 500 error in post listing page?

Tags: hooks, 500-internal-error

I am getting a 500 error in only post listing page. I checked code in admin and found this hook creating a problem:

```
admin_head-$hook_suffix
```

When I remove this hook, page works **fine**.

How can I solve 500 error without removing hook?

Comment: Enable WP error logging and show us your`wp-content/debug.log`.

Comment: Errors 500 indicate that something went very wrong, but give none indication of specifics. You would need to get to a _real_ error, likely buried somewhere in server logs, first.